# Apache Velocity and adding JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apache, velocity

Please forgive me as I've never used Apache Velocity before but I have to figure this out!

I'm using an adobe recommendation template for products and I'm now adding a star rating system into it as noted in the image below:

[image: star rating image]

However, as you can see the logic i have added (In JS) is only being executed the first time. and obviously not running through the loop, since it is in Velocity.

My question to the community is; how do i go about making this work?

I've tried for a day now to no avail, so ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Please see the code below! (And thanks!)

[The #foreach loops is the velocity, and everything between the script tags is my appended code]

```
<div class="line">
<h2>More for You</h2>
```

```
#set($count=1)

      #foreach($e in $entities)  
        #if($e.id != "" && $count < $entities.size() && $count <=18) 
          <li>
          <script type="text/javascript">

              var myString = $e.rating;
                if (myString >= 5) { myString = 5;} 

              var myRegexp2 = /\d(?!.*\d)/;
              var match2 = myRegexp2.exec(myString);
              var starIMG = "<img src='http://kirklands.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/3768-en_us/" + match + "_" + match2 + "/5/rating.gif' alt='' />";

              var myRegexp3 = /\d/;
              var match = myRegexp3.exec(myString);

                function myFunction() {
        return(match);
            }

          </script>
            <a class="productBlock" onclick="var s = s_gi(s_account);
            s.linkTrackVars='events,eVar21';
            s.linkTrackEvents='event16';
            s.events='event16';
            s.eVar21='';
            s.tl(this,'o','Product Detail Cross-Sell');" href="$e.pageUrl?icid=hpFS ">
              <img title="$e.name" alt="$e.name" src="$e.thumbnailUrl">
              <h3>$e.name</h3>
              <div id="starRating"><script>document.getElementById("starRating").innerHTML = 
              starIMG;</script></div>
              <p>$$e.value</p>
            </a>

          </li>
        #set($count = $count + 1)
      #end 
    #end
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="scroolBtn btnRight"><span class="btn" id="scrool-forward"></span></div>
</div>
```

jQuery(function () {
      jQuery('#scrool').scrollbox({
        direction: 'h',
        switchItems: 3,
        distance: 450,
        autoPlay:false
      });
      jQuery('#scrool-backward').click(function () {
        jQuery('#scrool').trigger('backward');
      });
      jQuery('#scrool-forward').click(function () {
        jQuery('#scrool').trigger('forward');
      });
    });

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Velocity template scripts for years but wild guess is an escaping problem. Everything you include in a velocity template is actually run by Velocity engine, you must escape $variable literals.

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences

**edit** No wait, you mean you wanted to run javascript code at server side, each foreach item step should evaluate javascript code?

Comment: Correct! Ideally I'd like the JS to execute through each iteration. 
But I'm not sure if that is possible? 

The only reason I don't want to do it in Velocity - is well, because i don't know how.

but I'll look into escaping?

Comment: Velocity cannot run javascript (client-side), you must use velocity scripting(server-side) which is a limited feature set compared to a browser javascript engine. You create StarIMG string inside a loop and output html tags. Velocity link I provided should have examples of Velocity scripting syntax.

Comment: Basic syntax is  $mybean.rating references to Mybean.getRating() getter. Try `#set( $startIMG = "sometext/$e.rating/continue.gif" )` then use that $variable in a html link. Should get you started and add if-then-else using velocity to cap rating values.

Comment: If Velocity script is too much or limited you probably should write entity.rating value to a div attribute. Use jQuery(document-ready or other trigger) client-side to loop div elements and insert stars.gif overlay image at client side. Probably more familiar because you can use javascript. Also dont use `<div id="starRating">..</div>` name for all product divs, id is a document wide unique value.

Comment: i've edited the code to use the value in the div and try iterate through the divs then using javascript to sub the value i.e: 3.4 back into the query string but it's now making all the divs the same value, but at least the image is showing?

Comment: Part one: 
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     

    $(".starIMGrating").each(function(){
     

    var myString = $(this).html()
    

       if (myString >= 5) { myString = 5;} 
     else{}
      
      /* alert(myString); */
    
     
      var myRegexp2 = /\d(?!.*\d)/;
      var match2 = myRegexp2.exec(myString);

 var myRegexp3 = /\d/;
      var match = myRegexp3.exec(myString);
      
  
        var starIMG = "<img src='http://kirklands.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/3768-en_us/"+match+"_"+ match2+"/5/rating.gif' alt='' />";

Comment: alert(match); 
      alert(starIMG);
      
       $(".starIMGrating").html(starIMG) 
       
       
       
           function myFunction() {
      return(match);
     

    }

       }); 
    });

Comment: Debug myString values before and after ‘if >= 5‘ expression.